# Is there a better way of doing associations? Ex: Product has many pictures and many parts

Tags: angular, mean-stack

I currently have a working code, but I would like to know if there is a better way of implementing relations in Angular 2. Below are my classes:

```
import { Picture } from '../picture/picture';
import { Part } from '../part/part';

export class Product {
    constructor(
        public title: string,
        public imageUrl: string,
        public description: string,
        public price: number,
        public productId?: string,              
        public pictures?: [Picture],
        public parts?: [Part]){}
}
//The same code for Part Class:
export class Picture {

    constructor(
        public name: string, 
        public pictureUrl: string,
        public productId?: string,
        public pictureId?: string){}
}
```

Below is my product.service just to get all products:

```
getProducts() {
  return this._http.get('http://localhost:3000/product')
    .map(response => {
      const data = response.json().obj; // from server route
      let objs: any[] = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let product = new Product(data[i].title, data[i].imageUrl, 
        data[i].description, data[i].price, data[i].id, 
        data[i].pictures, data[i].parts);
        objs.push(product);
    }
    this.products = objs;
  })
 .catch(error => Observable.throw(error.json()));
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with "relations" in your question? :)

Comment: An example of relations is a product has many pictures.

Comment: When I click on the product detail in my app, say iphone. I want to show the front, side, back views of the iphone. I also want to list all the parts included with iphone. Sorry, not relations, but associations: has one, has many. See rails association for further information.